# How long can you store the bones of a chicken in the refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, chicken

No odours can enter the place where I am keeping the bones in the refrigerator so contamination is minimized.

Comment: If raw, the same time as raw meat. If cooked, the same time as cooked chicken. Both depend on cumulative exposure to dangerous temperatures since time of death, but generally, not longer than 3-4 days for cooked, less for raw.

Comment: Masi: thanks for asking good question! You may find interesting chicken related question such as bones [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16316/how-to-use-bones-in-soups) and generally [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16314/which-parts-of-a-chicken-are-used-to-make-chicken-soup).

Comment: rumtscho: hey this solved my problem too (or is going to solve it), I was considering to pile up a huge amount of bones (never even considered that it may be unhealthy!). Now I find it odd that dogs can eat bones very long time. Is there some paper about this? Very well, bones have the protein (gelatin) but how does it go bad over time? Hopefully someone could write an answer about this...

Comment: rumtscho: I was enculturated in a school where they said that I can never eat something after heating it up once. Now you are saying "Both depend on cumulative exposure to dangerous temperatures since time of death". So is the key point "cumulative exposure" rather than just heating?

Comment: @hhh it is actually more complex than just "cumulative time", because it involves bacteria multiplication and death rates for every point in the temperature interval and the duration spent at this point. This is practically impossible for a cook to know, so the FDA specifies the rule of thumb: No more than 4 hours spent between 5°C and 60°C, cumulative since purchase (assuming the butcher followed correct procedures). It is very restrictive, but most people think it is sensible to follow it (and American restaurants are legally obliged to).

Comment: @hhh on a side note, please use the "@" sign before a nick when leaving a comment for somebody who wrote on the same question, answer or comment, so they can get a notification. Only the name isn't enough.

Comment: @hhh another point: if you want to stockpile bones, freeze them. They will keep for months that way. This question was about a refrigerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rumtscho gives the answer in the comments:

> No more than 4 hours spent between 5°C and 60°C, cumulative since
>   purchase (assuming the butcher followed correct procedures). It is
>   very restrictive, but most people think it is sensible to follow it
>   (and American restaurants are legally obliged to)

And about freezing which I will use:

> if you want to stockpile bones, freeze them. They will keep for months
>   that way. This question was about a refrigerator.